# Pegar o que está entre as aspas

Tags: c#, .net, string

Como eu faço para pegar somente oque esta dentro de aspas dupla, o problema eh o seguinte, ele esta lendo um arquivo txt q em cada linha tem um caminho de arquivo, como este abaixo

> "Dinosfuls Mods.bmd" 454545s 454545

Como eu faço para pegar somente essa parte sem as aspas?

> Dinosfuls Mods.bmd**
>
> file.Name = Dinosfuls Mods.bmd
>
> file.Hash = 454545s
>
> file.Size = 454545

```
public static void AddFile(string File)
{
    Globals.File file = new Globals.File();
    
    string texto = File.Split(' ')[0];

    int valorPos = texto.IndexOf(@"""") + 1;
    string valorEntreAspas = texto.Substring(valorPos, texto.IndexOf(@"""", valorPos) - valorPos);

    file.Name = valorEntreAspas;
    //file.Hash = File.Split(' ')[1];
    //file.Size = Convert.ToInt64(File.Split(' ')[2]);

    //Globals.Files.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: E qual seu problema?

Comment: esta pegando somente antes do espaço do arquivo le somente  "Dinofuls

Comment: Está um pouco difícil entender. Um dos motivos que está errando é que o problema não está bem definido, programação é detalhe, quando falta um ou está errado o código sai errado. O código faz várias coisas que só você sabe porque. Não temos informação suficiente da entrada de dados e a exata saída.

Comment: eu preciso que esse código pegue essa linha do txt  "Dinosfuls Mods.bmd" 454545s 454545, leia somente oque tem dentro das aspas e jogue dentro de uma variável...soh q nao sei como fazer...

Comment: essa linha "Dinosfuls Mods.bmd" 454545s 454545 fica na variavel texto.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Tem algumas coisas esquisitas neste código, vou tentar postar algo que parece ser o que resolve.

```
public static void AddFile(string texto) {
    int pos = texto.IndexOf("\"") + 1; //se achar nada causará erro
    var entreAspas = texto.Substring(pos, texto.IndexOf("\"", pos) - valorPos);
    texto = texto.Substring(texto.IndexOf("\"", valorPos) + 1);
    var palavras = texto.Split(' ');
    Globals.Files.Add(new Globals.File { Name = entreAspas, Hash = palavras[0], Size = Convert.ToInt64(palavras[1]));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/GetInsideQuotes.cs).

Comment: nao deu certo, vou tentar explicar denovo kkkk, tipo esse codigo eh responsavel por ler cada linha de um arquivo txt e cada linha do txt tem 3 colunas, eu preciso pegar somente a 1ª coluna tirar as aspas e colocar numa variavel...

Answer (score 1):

Tenta o seguinte código...
é só remover o que não é necessário.

```
        //Simulando o recebimento da string
        string str = "\"Dinosfuls Mods.bmd\" 454545s 454545";
        //Separa as colunas e pega a segunda contando que sempre vai vir duas aspas na string
        string primeiraCol = str.Split('\"')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Já pensou em usar uma expressão regular?

```
    public static void AddFile(string file)
    {
        string pattern = @"([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1";

        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        var match = rx.Match(file);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            var fileName = match.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
            var values  = file.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty).Split(' ');
            var hash = values[1];
            var size = values[2];
        }
    }
```